# How to allow only numerical data in a textbox

Tags: c#

I'm a new C# student and I've been working on my project, however, I can't seem to get some of my textboxes to act properly.  I need to ensure that some of my textboxes receive only numerical data.  Currently, my medication, surgery, labs, and rehab textboxes return their messageBox message when I fill in the textbox with a numerical value which is opposite of what they are supposed to do.

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int days;
            double medication;
            double surgery = 0;
            double labs = 0;
            double rehab = 0;

            if (int.TryParse(numDaysInHosp.Text, out days))
                if (days < 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Days In Hospital must be greater than zero.");
                }

            if (double.TryParse(medsCharges.Text, out medication))
                if (medsCharges.Text != "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Charges for Medication cannot be blank.");
                    medsCharges.Focus();
                }

            if (double.TryParse(surgCharges.Text, out surgery))
               if (surgCharges.Text != "")
               {
                  MessageBox.Show("Surgical Charges cannot be blank.");
                  surgCharges.Focus();
               }

            if (double.TryParse(labFees.Text, out labs))
               if (labFees.Text != "")
               {
                    MessageBox.Show("Lab Fees cannot be blank.");
                    labFees.Focus();
               }

            if (double.TryParse(rehabCharges.Text, out rehab))
               if (rehabCharges.Text != "")
               {
                    MessageBox.Show("Rehabilitation Charges cannot be blank.");
                    rehabCharges.Focus();
               }

            { 
                double dayChrgs = CalcDayChrgs(days);
                double miscChrgs = CalcMiscChrgs(medication, surgery, labs, rehab);
                double totlCost = CalcTotlChrgs(dayChrgs, miscChrgs);

                stayChrgsLabel.Text = dayChrgs.ToString("c");
                miscChrgsLabel.Text = miscChrgs.ToString("c");
                totlCostLabel.Text = totlCost.ToString("c");
                memberLevelLabel.Text = memberLevelLabel.ToString();

            }
        }
```

We are not allowed to use the keypress method to do this.  Additionally, I've tried using the following lines as well with negative results.

```
(string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox.Text))
if(TextBox.Text == "") 
if(TextBox.Text.Length == 0)
String.IsNullOrWhitespace()
```

What am I not seeing in my code?

Comment: I think the problem is that `double.TryParse` returns `true` if the input is valid, and your code seems to assume otherwise.

Comment: Another bit of advice: you really want to be using decimal, not double, when dealing with monetary values.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your approach here.

1. Every check you've written can only display a message **if the content can be parsed to the expected type**. If it cannot be parsed, then you'll never enter the `if` blocks and thus no message will ever be shown. That's the opposite of what you want, you want to show the message when it's *not* parseable to the expected type.
2. The checks for blanks also don't make sense.

```
if (medsCharges.Text != "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Charges for Medication cannot be blank.");
}
```

If the message is being shown, then the textbox is not blank (since it's `!= ""`). Combined with the first point, it seems like your expectations of true/false are inverted for most `if` statements you've written

3. Because you are nesting `if` statements, you will only show the error message if **both** checks succeed. But usually you'd want to display an error if **either** of the validation checks fail. Combine the error checks with an or (`||`) to ensure that *any* validation failure leads to the appropriate action being taken.
4. Even if you show the messages to the user, you're still not stopping the rest of the method from executing. Messages are nice for UX purposes but you shouldn't blindly rely on the user following the rules when informed of them. When the validation fails, **stop the calculation** (e.g. by using a `return` statement);
5. This makes no sense:

```
memberLevelLabel.Text = memberLevelLabel.ToString();
```

You are casting the label itself to a string and then setting the same label's `Text` value to that string. To what end?

6. You're doing homework:

> I'm a new C# student and I've been working on my project
>
> We are not allowed to use the keypress method to do this.

Talk to your teacher if you struggle with the task you've been assigned. There is a **deep level of misunderstanding on logical evaluations** in your code and no StackOverflow answer is going to be able to delve into it all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TextChanged` event to validate the input:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int pos = textBox1.SelectionStart;
  string result = "";
  foreach ( char c in textBox1.Text )
    if ( char.IsDigit(c) )
      result += c;
  textBox1.Text = result;
  textBox1.SelectionStart = pos;
}
```

We save the carret position next we parse the chars of the string to remove non digits then we update the Text property.

You can add conditions for sign and decimal separator:

```
  string separatorDecimal = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread
                            .CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
  bool hasDecimalSeparator = false;
  int posCarret = textBox1.SelectionStart;
  string result = "";
  for ( int index = 0; index < textBox1.Text.Length; index++ )
  {
    char c = textBox1.Text[index];
    if ( new string(c, 1) == separatorDecimal )
    {
      if ( hasDecimalSeparator )
        continue;
      else
      {
        hasDecimalSeparator = true;
        result += c;
      }
    }
    else
    if ( c == '+' || c == '-' )
    {
      if ( index == 0 )
        result += c;
    }
    else
    if ( char.IsDigit(c) )
      result += c;
  }
  textBox1.Text = result;
  textBox1.SelectionStart = posCarret;
```

If you can't use `TextChanged`, simply use the `Click` event of a `Button` instead.

If you can, you should use a `NumericUpDown` control instead of a `TextBox`.

So you will have a better UX and a simple UI validation behavior.

You can define `Minimum` and `Maximum` values.

You can get the entered `Value` that is a `decimal` using for example:

```
int value = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
```

You can hide the right arrows using this in the form constructor after `InitializeComponent()`:

```
numericUpDown1.Controls[0].Hide();
```

You can disallow text editing to allow only arrows by setting the `ReadOnly`property to `true` and `BackColor` to `White` or any color.

Don't set readonly to true and visible to false same time unless you want to disable the control.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Check if following code works for your scenario

```
        private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int days;
        double medication;
        double surgery = 0;
        double labs = 0;
        double rehab = 0;

        if (!int.TryParse(numDaysInHosp.Text, out days) || days == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Days In Hospital must be greater than zero.");
            numDaysInHosp.Focus();
        }
        else if (!double.TryParse(medsCharges.Text, out medication))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Charges for Medication cannot be blank.");
            medsCharges.Focus();
        }
        else if (!double.TryParse(surgCharges.Text, out surgery))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Surgical Charges cannot be blank.");
            surgCharges.Focus();
        }
        else if (!double.TryParse(labFees.Text, out labs))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Lab Fees cannot be blank.");
            labFees.Focus();
        }
        else if (!double.TryParse(rehabCharges.Text, out rehab))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Rehabilitation Charges cannot be blank.");
            rehabCharges.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Everything is ok");
            //double dayChrgs = CalcDayChrgs(days);
            //double miscChrgs = CalcMiscChrgs(medication, surgery, labs, rehab);
            //double totlCost = CalcTotlChrgs(dayChrgs, miscChrgs);

            //stayChrgsLabel.Text = dayChrgs.ToString("c");
            //miscChrgsLabel.Text = miscChrgs.ToString("c");
            //totlCostLabel.Text = totlCost.ToString("c");
            //memberLevelLabel.Text = memberLevelLabel.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon. Please elaborate _why_ you think the proposed fix is the answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Click textbox which you want to change>events>double click keypress event and write codes below. If yo try to write except number it wouldn't write.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
}
```

Edit: Sorry, You are not allowed to use keypress. I will update my answer.

Try to use **maskedtextbox** form control with numeric for just getting numbers.

**Not good but use code below:**

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "[^0-9]"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please give a reason why are you downvote this answer?Then,  I am going to correct it or correct it together for community. It works actually.